# R: Creating a new row for each group, with values being the difference of existing entries in the group

Tags: r

| Region | Age | Student Type | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 17 | Any | 32 |
| A | 17 | Full time | 24 |
| A | 18 | Any | 27 |
| A | 18 | Full time | 19 |
| B | 17 | Any | 22 |
| B | 17 | Full time | 14 |
| B | 18 | Any | 80 |
| B | 18 | Full time | 75 |

I am working with this dataset in R. I am hoping to create a new tow for each region and age, with student type being "Part time" and values being the values of "Any" - "Full time". It seems I can use lag in the process, but I was hoping to be more explicit, specifying it is "Any" - "Full time", as while this dataset is well organized there may be data sets where entries are reversed.

Ideally the result would look something like

| Region | Age | Student Type | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 17 | Any | 32 |
| A | 17 | Full time | 24 |
| A | 17 | Part time | 8 |
| A | 18 | Any | 27 |
| A | 18 | Full time | 19 |
| A | 18 | Part time | 8 |
| B | 17 | Any | 22 |
| B | 17 | Full time | 14 |
| B | 17 | Part time | 8 |
| B | 18 | Any | 80 |
| B | 18 | Full time | 75 |
| B | 18 | Part time | 5 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Region, Age) %>%
  summarize(Student.Type = "Part time",
            Values = abs(diff(Values))) %>%
  rbind(., df) %>%
  arrange(Region, Age, Student.Type)

   Region   Age Student.Type Values
   <chr>  <int> <chr>         <int>
 1 A         17 Any              32
 2 A         17 Full time        24
 3 A         17 Part time         8
 4 A         18 Any              27
 5 A         18 Full time        19
 6 A         18 Part time         8
 7 B         17 Any              22
 8 B         17 Full time        14
 9 B         17 Part time         8
10 B         18 Any              80
11 B         18 Full time        75
12 B         18 Part time         5
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, you could use `group_modify()` + `add_row()`.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Region, Age) %>%
  group_modify(~ {
    .x %>%
      summarise(StudentType = "Part time", Values = -diff(Values)) %>%
      add_row(.x, .)
  }) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 12 × 4
#    Region   Age StudentType    Values
#    <chr>  <int> <chr>           <int>
#  1 A         17 Any                32
#  2 A         17 Full time          24
#  3 A         17 Part time           8
#  4 A         18 Any                27
#  5 A         18 Full time          19
#  6 A         18 Part time           8
#  7 B         17 Any                22
#  8 B         17 Full time          14
#  9 B         17 Part time           8
# 10 B         18 Any                80
# 11 B         18 Full time          75
# 12 B         18 Part time           5
```